# Maths symbols in other languages

Tags: notation

I am a native English speaker, always educated in English. I always assumed that maths was a universal language (well, at least for Latin based languages). But I've now started tutoring a student in Switzerland and am discovering that Swiss (German) schools use different symbols for things. For instance, [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvAx6.jpg)

Now I'm wondering if I only know "English" maths. Does anyone know where I could find a list of mathematical symbols used in other languages (especially German)?

Many thanks

Comment: There is nothing strange in the use of *colon* for division; see [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Operation: Division](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html). I think that it derives from the symbol used for [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology).

Comment: Please show us more serious examples! The "official" source of notations in Switzerland is "Formulae, Tables and Concepts", published by the Swiss federation of Gymnasium teachers. Check there!

Comment: My student is only in Grade 8 and I've only been tutoring her for a short time, so we've only covered fractions and are now starting geometry. But thanks for the tip.